# Cannot send data from confluent platform to Elasticsearch with elastic sink connector. Exception: Tolerance exceeded in error handler

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to run a simple example to send kafka data to elasticsearch by using confluent platform with elastic-sink connector.
I'm using confluent platform version 6.0.0 and I installed the latest version of the elastic-sink-connector.
The configuration of my connector is the following:

```
{
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "e",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "topics": [
    "ciao"
  ],
  "connection.url": [
    "http://192.168.x.x:9200"
  ],
  "key.ignore": "true",
  "schema.ignore": "true"
}
```

I used kafkacat to send message to my topic "ciao", but as soon as I sent the data my connector failed.

I'm trying to see what the problem can be and I obtained this exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:472)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:366)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    ... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ciao': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"ciao\"; line: 1, column: 5]\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ciao': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"ciao\"; line: 1, column: 5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3560)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:754)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2734)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:472)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What is the problem?
I followed this tutorial without running confluent with docker but locally with confluent platform https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the stack trace for you and within that you can see

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: 
Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:366)
…
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unrecognized token 'ciao': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"ciao\"; line: 1, column: 5]
```

It looks like the message it's reading isn't valid JSON. You could try setting `"errors.tolerance" : "all"` if there's just a few misformed messages on the topic and other valid JSON that you do want to process.

See also [Error Handling in Kafka Connect and Elasticsearch Sink connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-to-elasticsearch/README.adoc#error-handling-in-kafka-connect-and-elasticsearch-sink-connector)

Comment: I tried to set "errors.tolerance": "all", and the connector runs well, but when I search the index into elasticsearch it does not exist.

Comment: In which case it sounds like it's more than just a few misformed messages, and instead there's something fundamentally wrong with the format of your data vs what the connector is expecting. Can you edit your question to include a sample of the data on the Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the configuration was wrong.
I wrote the correct configuration and now it works well.

The configuration is the following:

```
{
  "name": "e",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
    "topics": "ciao",
    "connection.url": "http://192.x.x.x:9200",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
  }
}
```